# create hierarchy of folders, and set permissions

Tags: bash, mkdir

`mkdir` has options:

- `-p` that creates all parent directories if missing
- `-m` which changes user rights.

Problem for me is, that `-m 755` is applied only to the leaf directory.

`mkdir -m 755 -p a/b/c` -> `c` has mode 755 but `a` and `a/b` have modes 700. (I want a and a/b to be also 755)

Is there easy solution? (or just iterate over parents and chmod each?)

Comment: No need to iterate, just use `chmod -R 755 a` after `mkdir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bit unexpected behaviour from mkdir, I would also assume the -m flag would have effect on all created directories, not just the leaf node.

I see two easy ways to do this:

1. `$ (umask 022; mkdir -p a/b/c)`
2. `$ install -d -m 755 a/b/c`

The umask controls all file creation done by the shell and is a mask of the permission bits set (this makes the values a bit hard to use).  Putting the two commands in parenthesis means it will only have effect for that sub shell.

Using the install tool is another option.  With the -d option, it behaves the same way as mkdir -p, but the -m flag will be used for all directories, not just the leaf node.  install is part of the coreutils package, and will most likely be available on any system.